# relationship between Javascript objects and variables

Tags: javascript, object, oop, variables

In javascript, objects are considered as variables(At least according to my knowledge).

ex:

```
var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = 'Ford';
myCar.model = 'Mustang';
myCar.year = 1969;
```

I do not understand the logic behind this. Can this be true even in languages like c++(i.e can C++ objects be considered as variables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing several concepts here. A "variable" is a way of referring to an object, and in languages like JavaScript, a way of *retaining a reference* to it so it doesn't go away until you're done with it.

In C++ there are also variables, but they're more as a convenience to the programmer as once that code is compiled they don't exist in the same fashion as they do in JavaScript, they can often get optimized away.

In your code you have a variable `myCar` which lets you manipulate the object. If you just did this:

```
new Object()
```

That creates an object, but effectively throws it away. In JavaScript this gets garbage collected and cleaned up. In C++ that's a *memory leak*.

You can have objects without variables, and you can have variables without objects, like this:

```
var x = 9
console.log(typeof(x))
// => number
```

Where `x` is a variable and it's just a number, not an object.

Saying "objects are considered variables" is like saying "a house can be considered its street address". It's not true though. It's a building that happens to have a particular street address, but you can move the house around, and some houses even have wheels on them for this purpose. Likewise, addresses can change but the house remains the same.

A street address is a way to *refer* to a house, just as a variable can *refer* to an object. It could also refer to an empty lot, as `undefined` in JavaScript.

> Tip: It's generally a good practice to use `let` or `const` now instead of the more generic, and sometimes troublesome `var`.

Answer (score 4):

Technically the `myCar` that you created is a variable which stores the instance of the object that you created using `new Object()`.

Variables are like a box where in you can store specific data and access it along your code.

So variables can come in many shape or form depending on what data you put on it. It can come as a string, objects, array, number or boolean.. **It does not always have to be an object.**